# Search for the exact child node with HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

`getElementsByTagName("*")` will get you the child nodes in `Depth First Search in Pre-order`. The problem is if I search for a string inside the node's HTML, there is no way to tell the same is inside another child node that is going to be returned by the `getElementsByTagName("*")`. So, is there any way to iterate nodes from leaves to root?
Most probably a `DFS-Post order` will do the trick!

For example:

```
  <div id=""master">
    <div id="id1">
      <div id="id2">
        <span>text</span><i>more text</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If we are searching for `<i>more text</i>`, then innerHTML of first element for the result as well as all the subsequent elements will match. But I want only the exact child to match the string. If we are starting from the leaves, then we can `break` away after finding the text.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to actually do this text search, make sure the [`nodeType === 3`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp) and then check the [`nodeValue`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodevalue.asp) for the string. The node you actually want to return is the `parentNode` of said node.

I think it's a bad idea in general, though, and if you expect the content of said element to change (and that's why you're searching it) to attach an event handler to listen for changes, instead.

Answer (score 0):

this is slightly more than you nominally need, but does exactly what you want.

it allows you to search for nodes using a number of criteria based on properties, giving an array of all the matches.

```
function getNodes(prop, needle, blnMatch, node){
    var results=[], any=(needle==null); 
      node=node||document.documentElement;
      if(node.splice){ node={childNodes:node}; }
    for(var it, i=0, kids=node.childNodes;it=kids[i];i++){
        if(it.childNodes.length){
            results=results.concat(getNodes(prop, needle, blnMatch, it));
        }
        switch(true){
            case    any && it[prop]:
            case    it[prop]===needle:  
            case blnMatch && !!String(it[prop]).match(needle):
             results[results.length]=it; 
        }
    }
   return results;
}//end getNodes()


//for your purpose, you can use it to reach the actual textNode as such:

var node=getNodes("data","more text")[0];
alert([node.data, node.nodeName]) // shows : "more text, #text"
```

note that you can use it in many more ways to get specific on any given property:

```
getNodes("nodeType", 3);
getNodes("nodeValue", "more text");
getNodes("nodeName", /^(a|link)$/i, true);
```